# Is it possible or a common technique to sandbox kernel mode drivers?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, device-driver

I see that kernel mode drivers are risky as they run in privileged mode, but are there any monolithic kernel's that do any form of driver/loadable module sandboxing or is this really the domain of microkernels?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are platforms with "monolithic" (for some definition of monolithic) kernels that do driver sandboxing for some drivers. Windows does this in more recent versions with the user mode driver framework. There are two reasons for doing this:-

1. It allows isolation. A failure in a user mode driver need not bring down the whole system. This is important for drivers for hardware which is not considered system critical. An example of this might be your printer, or your soundcard. In those cases if the driver fails, it can often simply be restarted and the user often won't even notice this happened.
2. It makes writing and debugging drivers much easier. Driver writers can use regular user mode libraries and regular user mode debuggers, without having to worry about things like IRQL and DPCs.

The other poster said there is no sense to this. Hopefully the above explains why you might want to do this. Additionally, the other poster said their is a performance concern. Again, this depends on the type of the driver. In Windows this is typically used for USB drivers. In the case of USB drivers, the driver is not talking directly to the hardware directly anyway regardless of the mode that the driver operates in - they are talking to another driver which is talking to the USB host controller, so there is much less overhead of user mode communication than there would be if you were writing a driver that had to bit bang IO ports from user mode. Also, you would avoid writing user mode drivers for hardware which was performance critical - in the case of printers and audio hardware the user mode transitions are so much faster than the hardware itself, that the performance cost of the one or two additional mode context switches is probably irrelevant.

So sometimes it is worth doing simply because the additional robustness and ease of development make the small and often unnoticeable performance reduction worthwhile.

Comment: I think that we talk about kernel mode drivers ). And very small group of drivers can be written in UMDF (and if you want some options, like concurent access as i remember, you can`t switch to UMDF too).

Comment: There are certainly limitations on what can be done from UMDF, but that is simply a function of UMDF not being a complete technology yet - they did the support for the things you'd want to move to user mode first, like printer drivers where concurrent access isn't a problem. The question doesn't specifically ask about kernel mode drivers.

Answer (score 0):

There are no sense in this sandboxing, OS fully trust to drivers code. Basically this drivers become part of kernel. You can't failover after FS crash or any major subsystem of kernel. Basically it`s bad (failover after crash, imagine that you can do after storage driver of boot disk crash?), because can lead to data loss for example.
And second - sandboxing lead to perfomance hit to all kernel code.